# Is there an equivalent of spriting for SVG images in web pages?

Tags: css, svg, css-sprites

SVG images aren’t bitmaps, so (unless I’m missing something) you can’t do spriting like you can with other images files used on web pages (see http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites).

But is there an equivalent mechanism to display only part of an SVG image as a CSS background?

E.g. imaginary syntax:

```
div.my-special-svg-div {
    background-image: url(sprite-image.svg#one-shape-in-the-svg-file);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use 'traditional' CSS sprite techniques to slice up SVG images with background position, [here's a quick example](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/css-background-sprites.html), though it does get a little confusing if you also start using background-size.  It's probably easier if you define a size on your SVG image:

```
<svg version="1.1" 
     xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="320"
     height="240"
     viewBox="0 0 320 240">
```

Comment: This is quite helpful answer, and he is defining the size in the actual SVG image file itself.

Answer (score 4):

One approach I’ve tried that isn’t spriting, but achieves similar aims, is to include url-encoded SVG images directly in the CSS file, using data URIs.

E.g.

```
background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Crect%20fill%3D%22%23CCD%22%20%20width%3D%22100%25%22%20height%3D%22100%25%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3Crect%20fill%3D%22%23039%22%20width%3D%22100%25%22%20height%3D%22100%25%22%20rx%3D%221em%22%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E);
```

(See http://intertwingly.net/blog/2008/09/07/SVG-via-CSS)

So, all your SVG images end up in the CSS file. Gzipping should squish multiple SVG files in one CSS file quite nicely.

As far as I can tell, the CSS above works in Opera 9.5+, IE 9 beta, Safari 5, and Chrome 6. Doesn’t seem to work in Firefox as of 3.6, or earlier versions of the other browsers.

Comment: Note that it will work in Firefox 4.0 betas: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=231179

Comment: Interesting discussion on possible spriting via IDs in the comments there, from around https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=231179#c38

Comment: Yeah, after I'd tried it I thought it was worth bringing the idea up ;)  BTW, you can use 'traditional' CSS sprite techniques to slice up SVG images with background position, though it does get a little confusing if you also start using background-size.

Comment: @robertc: ah, sure — I haven’t done much with SVG, but you can specify pixel dimensions and x/y coordinates, can’t you? So I guess that would work for spriting. If you’ve got any experience with that and would like to write it up as an answer, you would be most deserving of upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SVG Stacks:

http://simurai.com/post/20251013889/svg-stacks

Comment: link broken now :(

Answer (score -12):

SVG isn't even technically supported by W3C standards. It won't even work in IE without a plugin. Maybe you'll find some obscure Mozilla plugin that lets you do that but as far as I know your code won't validate.

Comment: “SVG isn't even technically supported by W3C standards.” — How do you mean? [It *is* a W3C standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-SVG11-20030114/).

Comment: “It won't even work in IE without a plugin.” — Seems to work in IE 9 beta without a plug-in, as I said.

Comment: “as I know your code won't validate” — which code? The CSS I’ve put above validates just fine.

Comment: Apart from that, great answer.