# load div only for mobile devices with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mobile

Is it possible to load a div if a mobile is detected or if a resolution is lower than 641px?
I have different menus for desktop and for mobile. Mobile menu uses image svg sprite, but for desktop i don't want that svg image to load to save HTTP request.
I can hide the div based on media queries, but how can i at least prevent the image from being loaded, or load the intire menu div only for mobile?
What is the best approach to this?

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent the image from being loaded in certain condition's

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
  if(yourCondition){
    $("img").removeAttr("src");
  }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe this approach will be best for me.

Answer (score 1):

https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/wiki/Mobile_Detect

check above link, you can just use it in if else statement to show hide div on basis of device type

```
<?php
// Written By Adam Khoury @ developphp.com - March 26, 2010
// PHP swapping CSS style sheets for target device layouts
// Make your index page of your site a .php file instead of .html
 $styleSheet = "default.css";
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; // Put browser name into local variable

if (preg_match("/iPhone/", $agent)) { // Apple iPhone Device
// Set style sheet variable value to target your iPhone style sheet
   $styleSheet = "iphone.css";

} else if (preg_match("/android/", $agent)) { // Google Device using Android OS
// Set style sheet variable value to target your Android style sheet
$styleSheet = "android.css";

}
?>
```

above code is simply taken from http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=310, check the complete code if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ill check out this solution.

Comment: if u think that was useful, please mark it is as answer, welcome!!

Comment: @ManMohanVyas This doesn't prevent images from loading. Read this https://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/

Answer (score 0):

If your biggest problem is to prevent loading some images if not needed I would recommend to stay with media query. 
If you load different css-files (depending on media) you can add the needed images  as "background-image:".
This should also work for SVG Spite.

[How to use SVG Sprite Sheet as CSS background-image while maintaining aspect ratio and scalability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956636/how-to-use-svg-sprite-sheet-as-css-background-image-while-maintaining-aspect-rat)