# Same icon different sizes with gulp svg sprite?

Tags: css, gulp, css-sprites, svg-sprite

Im using gulp-svg-sprite https://github.com/jkphl/gulp-svg-sprite

Is it possible to use the same icon at different sizes? Prior to spriting this was easy and in fact was one of the things I like most about SVGs:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZQvYN

```
.icon-small,
.icon-large {
    background-image: url(https://lincolnloop.com/static/assets/img/lincolnloop-mark.9b93136b4561.svg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.icon-small {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.icon-large {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

However now that I'm using a sprite I cant use this solution as the background-size comes from the mixin. Even if I overwrote this then the background-position would be made wrong.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXezaK

```
.icon-small,
.icon-large {
    background-image: url(https://scotthsmith.com/projects/social-icons/blue/IconGrid.svg?v1.11);
  background-size: auto 400px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.icon-small {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.icon-large {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: can you post your sample svg sprite instead of the png example?

Comment: @Thoran Ive updated my question.

Comment: could transform-scale work? http://codepen.io/hkh222/pen/xVQBMO or do you want a more proper solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you don't have text on your svg. Then using `transform: scale(2)` should fix it:

```
.icon-large {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: scale(2)
}
```

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956636/how-to-use-svg-sprite-sheet-as-css-background-image-while-maintaining-aspect-rat) seem to be discussing similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to specify your width and height in ems, and then use font-size to scale your icon.

More information can be read on this blog post:
https://www.liquidlight.co.uk/blog/article/creating-svg-sprites-using-gulp-and-sass/